# How do I check the order of a UL by the list item IDs?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following `<ul>` that is sortable using jQuery UI.

```
<ul id="sortable1" class='droptrue'>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item-3">K</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item-2">I</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item-4">E</li>
    <li class="ui-state-default" id="item-1">M</li>
</ul>

$("#sortable1").on( "sortstop", function( event, ui ) {
      check to see if the order of the ul is item-1 to item-4
} );
```

I want to check after a user re-arranges the order to see if the list spells MIKE, or in other words, the ul is arranged incrementally by ID from item-1 to item-4. Any thoughts? Cheers

Comment: something like, `list_thing = document.getElementById('sortable1')`

if (list_thing.elements[0].value == "M" && list_thing.elements[1].value == "I" && //(and so on for the other two))

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#sortable1").on( "sortstop", function( event, ui ) {
    var word = '';
    $(this).children('li').each(function() {
        word += $(this).text();
    });
    if (word == "MIKE") {
        alert ("You win!");
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `item-x` index is always incremental then try

```
$("#sortable1").on("sortstop", function (event, ui) {
    var valid = true;
    $("#sortable1 > li").each(function (i) {
        if (this.id != 'item-' + (i + 1)) {
            valid = false;
            return false;
        }
    })
    if (valid) {
        console.log(valid)
    }
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6QqJe/)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$("#sortable1").sortable({
    stop: function (e, ui) {
        if($('li', this).text()==='MIKE') alert('MIKE');
    }
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/byjjG/)**